# Is Proof by Resolution really needed here?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I'm doing a problem in the book but this problem (where they ask me to use proof by resolution) seems unnecessary:

$p\iff r$

$r$

$\therefore p$

By definition of IFF, this seems true, but they ask me to prove by resolution? How do I go about it? If p IFF r is true, and r is true, by definition of If and Only If, doesn't that justify p being true?

Comment: Your argument is sound... but if the exercise ask you to use resolution, probably is because you have to practice with it.

Answer (score 4):

We want to prove :

> $((p \rightarrow r) \land (r \rightarrow p), r \vDash p$ ---**(*)**.

Due to the equivalence between $a \rightarrow b$ with $\lnot a \lor b$, the above is equivalent to :

> $[(\lnot p \lor r) \land (\lnot r \lor p) \land r] \vDash p$

and this in turn is equivalent to :

> $\vDash [(\lnot p \lor r) \land (\lnot r \lor p) \land r ] \rightarrow p$.

We know that the a formula is *valid* **iff** its negation is *unsatisfiable*.

Thus, in order to prove **(*)**, we have to show that :

> > $[(\lnot p \lor r) \land (\lnot r \lor p) \land r] \land \lnot p$

is unsatisfiable.

Thus, we have to apply [Resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) to the set of clauses :

> > $\{ \lnot p \lor r, \lnot r \lor p, r, \lnot p \}$

and deriving the *empty clause*.

This shows that the set of clauses is *unsatisfiable*, and thus the argument is *valid*.