# Resolution Refutation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am solving a few questions to better understand the way resolution works and now i've come across this question which has no explicit conclusion and I am supposed to use 'Resolution Refutation' to a set of clauses! I am having difficulty understanding what exactly this means, is it ok to choose any of the clauses and negate them and then try to arrive at a contradiction?

Posting the whole question here can be perceived as posting a homework and so I am not doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the [Resolution method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) amounts to prove that a set $\{ ϕ_1,ϕ_2,\ldots, ϕ_n \}$ of formulae *logically imply* a formula $\psi$, or equivalently that the sentence :

> (1) $\quad \vDash ϕ_1 \land ϕ_2 \land \ldots \land ϕ_n \rightarrow \psi$ is *valid*,

showing that the set $\{ ϕ_1,ϕ_2,\ldots, ϕ_n, \lnot \psi \}$ is *unsatisfiable*.

Th method needs that the sentence (1) is transformed into a conjunctive normal form with the conjuncts viewed as elements in a set $S$ of [clauses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)).

---

We can also apply the method to a set $\{ ϕ_1,ϕ_2,\ldots, ϕ_n \}$ of formulae to show that it is *satisfiable* or not.

If the application of the method derives the *empty clause*, then we can conclude that the set is *unsatisfiable*, which is equivalent to say that :

> $ϕ_1 \land ϕ_2 \land \ldots \land ϕ_{n-1} \rightarrow \lnot ϕ_n$ is *valid*.

Comment: I am familiar with the method where a ψ is mentioned, my problem I have no explicit ψ mentioned! I just have about 10 ϕ and I am supposed to do resolution refutation!

Comment: @AadiDroid - Ok: apply definition : "resolution is a rule of inference leading to a refutation theorem-proving technique for sentences in propositional logic and first-order logic. In other words, iteratively applying the resolution rule in a suitable way allows for telling whether a propositional formula is satisfiable and for proving that a first-order formula is unsatisfiable." Apply it to $ϕ_1∧ϕ_2∧…∧ϕ_{10}$ to prove that it is satisfiable or not ...

Comment: That makes sense, and that is what i've been trying to do for a couple of days now. I am running into loops. Is it safe to negate one of the statements and then apply the rules to lead to a box?

Comment: @AadiDroid - as per the first answer : "it would be recommend to see the whole question"... Having said that, the set initial $S$ of statements is what it is. If applying resolution you will end with a set $S'$ which do **not** include the *empty clause*, $S'$, and so also the original $S$, is *satisfiable*.

Comment: You can see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940513/is-proof-by-resolution-really-needed-here) a simple example ...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to post the whole question, so we can understand the.conext of your problem. However, as you posted it, I would rather bet you are requested to use the **resolution method**, i.e. verify whether one of the formulae $\phi_1, \phi_2, ... \phi_n$ in a formulae of the form $\phi_1\wedge \phi_2 \wedge ... \wedge \phi_n$ is **false**.

Obviously not every formula is given so. Fortunatelly we have algebraic manipulations techniques to provide its convertion to its **conjunctive normal form**, such that every $\phi_i$ stands for a propositional letter $p_i$ or its negation $\neg p_i$. The classic example are the distributivity property, De Morgan laws and so, that you probably know well.

Good work!